# How to defer a method in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a tab element `competences`, in this tab content I have one input filed `ref="search"`.

```
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a @click="competencesTabClick" aria-controls="Company" aria-selected="true" class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1" id="tab1-tab" ref="tab1" role="tab">Competences
            </a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item" v-if="authrzCompetencesEdit">
            <a @click="competencesByUser(0)" aria-controls="other" aria-selected="false" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2" id="tab2-tab" role="tab">Logs</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">

        <div aria-labelledby="tab1-tab" class="tab-pane fade show active" id="tab1" role="tabpanel">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="form-group">

                        <input @keyup="search($event)" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" ref="search" placeholder="Search" type="text">

                    </div>
                </div>
....
```

When I click on that tab I call this method: `@click="competencesTabClick"` to set focus to the input `ref="search"` above.

the problem (correct me if i'm wrong) is: the element is not loaded yet at that time.

So i'm wondering if there is a way to defer `competencesTabClick` method until the input element is loaded!

here the function `competencesTabClick` :

```
            competencesTabClick(){
                   this.$refs.search.focus();
            },
```

Comment: Have you tried nextTick ? https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick. Another solution could be to add this method to your competences component and call it on mounted ?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to defer until the UI is updated, you can use the `nextTick` function. According to the [Vue docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick), `nextTick` has the following purpose:

> Defer the callback to be executed after the next DOM update cycle. Use it immediately after you’ve changed some data to wait for the DOM update.

Use it like this:

```
competencesTabClick(){
    this.$nextTick(function() {this.$refs.search.focus()});
},
```

Comment: unfortunately it's not working ! but with `this.$nextTick` it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap `this.$refs.search.focus()` in a setTimeout. So, if will load after sometime. Like that:

```
competencesTabClick(){
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.$refs.search.focus()
  }, 200)
}
```

or you can also use this.$nextTick like that:

```
competencesTabClick(){
  this.$nextTick(function () {
    this.$refs.search.focus()
  })
}
```

You can know more about nextTick [here](https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2019/01/22/vue-what-is-next-tick/)

Hope it helps !!

Comment: There are many solutions to call a function once the component is rendered and setTimeout would be the worst one IMO.

Comment: Thanks :it works with `setTimeout`, but not with `this.$nextTick`